# UnsatisfiedLinkError with RXTX on Tomcat (used to work)

Tags: java, tomcat, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm just finishing off a Tomcat web application that uses the RXTX library for serial output.

I have previously had problems with external libraries on Tomcat, which I fixed through endless trial and error. I managed to fix the last problem by putting the DLL file somewhere deep in the file system which I can no longer find.

Anyway, through the development process, I've managed to run the server with no problems, but now that I've exported a war file (which I have not yet used), I'm getting the following error when I try to run the project from Eclipse:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path
```

I've put the library in the WEB-INF/lib folder, and mapped to it in the build path and deployment assembly. I just don't understand what else could be needed and why did it work before and not now.

1. What is going on here and how do I fix it.
2. I need to port this application from Windows to a Raspberry Pi. How do I prevent this from happening again there?

Comment: It seems to me it is easiest to be able to pass something like `-Djava.library.path=C:/lib/rxtx-lib.dll` to the Tomcat JVM. You can do that either in catalina.sh, or a Windows-equivalent of Linux's `/etc/default/tomcat`.

Comment: Never mind, I found the problem. A java update got rid of the RXTXSerial.dll in the jre.